# htaccess rewrite rule seo friendly not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

**I want to change this URL:**

```
example.com/services-details.php?service_id=1
```

**To:**

```
example.com/services-details/1
```

**Here is the code for `.htaccess` file**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

#SEO FRIENDLY URL

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ services-details.php?service_id=$1
```

#### Update (fixed)

**Step 1:**
Add this code in your `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# SEO FRIENDLY URL

# Redirect "/services-details.php?service_id=<num>" to "/services-details/<num>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^service_id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^(services-details)\.php$ /$1/%1 [QSD,R=301,L]

# Rewrite "/services-details/<num>" back to "services-details.php?service_id=<num>"
RewriteRule ^(services-details)/(\d+)$ $1.php?service_id=$2 [L]
```

**Step 2:**
Add this code (on the top) inside the ` HTML element

```
<base href="/">
```

After the followed steps it should work.

#### Info

Don't forget to change the link name `services-details`!

Comment: Where are you putting the `.htaccess` file? What values can `service_id` take? Is it numeric only?

Comment: @MrWhite - The .htaccess file is in the public_html file of the server. the service id can only take values as numeric (int) example: services-details.php?service_id=12.

Comment: "when I click of one of the services options" - Sorry, you need the `QSD` flag on the redirect rule (I've updated my answer). However, you should already be linking to `/services-details/1` internally, not `/services-details.php?service_id=1`. (`.htaccess` alone does not change your URLs.)

Comment: @MrWhite I updated the code but now I see only a blank page (404) do you know why? I also updated the question to give more information about it.

Comment: You've only got half the code in your update?! You need both the rewrite (first rule in my answer) and the second rule (which you have above, although this is optional).

Comment: @MrWhite thanks it works. There is only one problem left and that is when I want to visit the home page (index.php) it redirects to: example.com/services-details/index.php. Normally it has to redirect to: example.com/index.php. And when I want to visit other service-details page example: example.com/services-details/1 to service-details/2 is sends me to: example.com/services-details/services-details.php?service_id=2

Comment: That doesn't really have anything to do with these rules as such. That sounds like you are using a relative URL to link to your homepage. Since the page is now at a different path depth, any relative URL is going to be resolved relative to the current URL-path, ie. `/services-details/`. See the following question on the Webmasters stack (the same principle applies): https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

Comment: @MrWhite Thankyou for your help full solutions. It worked after I added the  <base href="/">. Hope this can help other people out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ services-details.php?service_id=$1
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$`) is only matching a single path-segment, whereas the requested URL has two, ie. `/services-details/1` - you need to match `service-details`.

And I'm assuming the `service_id` is always numeric.

For example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# SEO FRIENDLY URL

RewriteRule ^(services-details)/(\d+)$ $1.php?service_id=$2 [L]
```

Since you are rewriting to the same, you might as well capture `service-details` to avoid repetition.

There would seem to be no need for the filesystem checks, since I don't imagine `/services-details/<number>` to match a file or directory?

---

Note that if you are *changing* an existing URL structure where the old URLs have been indexed by search engines or linked to by third parties then you should also implement a 301 redirect from the old URL (ie. `/services-details.php?service_id=<number>`) to the new URL (ie. `/services-details/<number>`) in order to preserve SEO.

For example, the following "redirect" would need to go *before* the existing "rewrite" (above):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^service_id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^(services-details)\.php$ /$1/%1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `QSD` flag is required to remove the original query string from from the redirect response.

#### Summary

Your `.htaccess` file should look like this with the rules combined:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# SEO FRIENDLY URL

# Redirect "/services-details.php?service_id=<num>" to "/services-details/<num>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^service_id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^(services-details)\.php$ /$1/%1 [QSD,R=301,L]

# Rewrite "/services-details/<num>" back to "services-details.php?service_id=<num>"
RewriteRule ^(services-details)/(\d+)$ $1.php?service_id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: @BilalOzturk You can modify the existing rules to add an extra parameter. (Or duplicate if you need both.) This is left as an exercise for the reader ;). Come back if you get stuck. If there is anything you do not understand about the directives I've posted then please ask. The [Apache docs on mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) are a good source of information: [Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) and [Reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)